# Why is this branch always true using clap 4?

Tags: rust, clap

I would like to have a command line in Rust using clap 4 which allows this:

```
app --wait
```

If `--wait` is present start a function. If is NOT present do nothing.

I'm trying the below code with no luck: **the `if command.contains_id("wait")` is always true! With or without `--wait` as argument, why?**

```rust
let command = Command::new("")
    .arg(
        Arg::new("wait")
            .long("wait")
            .required(false)
            .num_args(0)
            .help("Wait..."),
    )
    .get_matches();

if command.contains_id("wait") {
    do_wait().await;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [clap4 documentation](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) for `default_value`:

> Value for the argument when not present.
>
> NOTE: If the user does not use this argument at runtime ArgMatches::contains_id will still return true. If you wish to determine whether the argument was used at runtime or not, consider ArgMatches::value_source.

So it would seem that `default_value` is taking affect. Why?
I'm not completely certain but it would seem that `Arg::new` uses defaults from `Arg::default`. This defaults `default_vals` to an empty vec, which wouldn't work on anything other than `num_args(0)`, but does work in your case b/c you have no args.

So it looks like your solution is to use `value_source` instead of `contains_id`, however you should not use num_args like this.

Instead use `.action(ArgAction::SetTrue)` like so:

```
Arg::new("wait")
                .long("wait")
                .action(ArgAction::SetTrue)
                .help("Wait ...")
```

See the flags section [here](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_tutorial/index.html#flags) for more details.